# Can I find out why this question was deleted?

Tags: support

Can I find out why this question was deleted and whether there are changes that could allow it to be undeleted? I have found an answer and would like to post that.

- https://superuser.com/questions/1686639/why-does-access-recalculate-a-stored-query-when-i-copy-it-can-i-tell-it-not-to

Comment: It was deleted because it wasn’t (answered, commented, nor edited) since it was submitted in November 2021.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/auto-deleted-questions

Comment: AIUI your free to post a question and answer it yourself. So for you to share your answer an undelete is not a requirement.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - No, when the question is deleted, it's hidden from other users and does not accept answers.

Comment: @Mokubai - If it was deleted because it had no answers, and I want to answer it now, can you undelete it so I can answer it?

Comment: @NewSites, yes I understand that, he can post the question again, can he not?

Comment: The linked help article provides a link to [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309526/355310) and one of the answers [explicitly advises re-asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310266/355310), so this should be an option.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - The author should focus on improving the existing question so it can be undeleted instead of submitting the same question that was already not answered after 2 years.

Comment: @Ramhound, but I can not even find that question anymore (following that URL) so assumed *really* deleted, as in gone. Can author still see and edit this question then?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - The author of a deleted question can see their own deleted question.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you, understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://superuser.com/q/1686639/116475 was deleted by Stack Exchange's automated question deletion script (aka, Roomba) as it has a score of 0, low views, no answers, and fewer than 2 comments.

Proposal: [Decrease the required view count to prevent Roomba deletion when score = 0 on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179)

I've personally had well over 100 questions deleted by Stack Exchange's automated question deletion script.